# Magento error in system log Price.php on line 388 explode() expects parameter 2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I`m trying to fix this error from system.log but i don`t know there to start. Can someone help me?

ERR (3): Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given  in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php on line 388

Regards,
Alin

Comment: edit the formatting of your post

Comment: Add this line in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php